# Handling wildcard '*' operator in string matching using KMP-Algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, string-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

How should I handle the case when the pattern to be matched contains the wildcard character, `*`, such as `AB*C`, which is present is the text, `ABEFGCS` (here `*` consumes characters `EFG`)  using the KMP-Algorithm ?

What modification in the algorithm can solve this problem ?

Comment: `*` is greedy in nature.. I would just match for AB in text and then C after AB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually I got it, leaving answer for reference, we can simply break the string about the wildcard operator, apply KMP on each part, and check whether each part is a sub-string or not, also, whether the parts are contiguous or not can be checked in linear time, hence the overall time complexity is still linear.

Comment: My time complexity analysis when there are `k` asterisk: break `pattern` string into at most `k+1` part, search each subpattern in `target text` get `k+1` sorted indices.
Create `k` monotonic pointer like which in mergesort, This can found all matches in time of `O(km+n)` and space `O(k+n)` ( e.g. in python combine `next` and `yield` ). Where `m` is length of `text` string, n is length of `pattern` string.