# Python: Find If Substring Exists in String Including Wildcard

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures, string-matching

I want to create a function that accepts two inputs, `fullstring` and `substring`. If the substring exists in the fullstring, the function should return `True`. Otherwise, it will return `False`. If the substring contains a wildcard (*), the wildcard can represent any *single* character.

For example:

```
arg1: fullstring = "hitherehello"
arg2: substring = "the*e
output: True
```

What I've tried:
The below is a function that matches substring with the parent string, but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate the wildcard.

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    len_ss = len(sub_string)
    for i in range(len(string) - len_ss + 1):
        if string[i:i+len_ss] == sub_string:
            return True

    return False
```

Constraints:
I cannot use regex or built-in python functions like `find`.

Comment: Break the substring up into non-wildcard parts, and test each of the parts individually.

Comment: Can there only be a single wildcard?

Comment: There could be multiple wildcards but each should always represent a single symbol

Comment: If you're interested in a more efficient strategy using KMP someone answered their own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817178/handling-wildcard-operator-in-string-matching-using-kmp-algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def search(fullstring, substring):
    def check(s1, s2):
        for a, b in zip(s1, s2):
            if a != b and b != "*":
                return False
        return True

    for i in range(len(fullstring) - len(substring) + 1):
        if check(fullstring[i : i + len(substring)], substring):
            return True

    return False


print(search("hitherehello", "the*e"))
```

Prints:

```
True
```

---

More tests:

```
print(search("hiXherehello", "*he*e")) # True
print(search("hitherXhello", "the*e")) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for each 'wildcard' part in the string, return the positions and check afterwards if the follow up:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string, lastIndex):
    len_ss = len(sub_string)
    for i in range(len(string) - len_ss + 1):
        if string[i:i + len_ss] == sub_string and lastIndex < i + len_ss:
            return i + len_ss
    return -1


def count_wrapper(string, sub_string, index):
    positions = []
    for wild_sub_string in sub_string.split('*'):
        index = count_substring(string, wild_sub_string, index)
        positions.append(index)
    # check pairwise
    return all([x + 2 == y for x, y in zip(*[iter(positions)] * 2)])


print(count_wrapper("there", "the*e", 0))
print(count_wrapper("thera", "the*e", 0))
print(count_wrapper("theresa", "the*e*a", 0))
```

Out:

```
True
False
True
```

Comment: Maybe an off-by-one error somewhere. This returns False: `count_wrapper("hitherehello", "ll*", 0)`

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
def check_all_substrings(index, string, substrings):
    for ss in substrings:
        if string[index:index+len(ss)] != ss:
            return False

        # If we matched, move the index along by the length of the substring + 1, so we skip a character
        index = index + len(ss) + 1
    return True

def match(string, substring):
    i = 0
    substrings = substring.split('*')

    while (i < (len(string) - len(substring))):

        if check_all_substrings(i, string, substrings):
            return True

        i += 1

    return False

# match substring
assert match("hitherehello", "there")

#match substring with 1 wild card
assert match("hitherehello", "the*e") 

# match 
assert match("hithat", "h*t*a")

# wild cards should match exactly 1 character
assert not match("hitherrrrehello", "the*e")

# do not match invalid substrings
assert not match("hithat", "the*e")
assert not match("hithat", "there")
```